# DataAnnotations in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am try to use DataAnnotation Required in MVC4 with ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName like this
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Texts), ErrorMessageResourceName = "zname", ErrorMessage = null)]
but it's not work and display defualt error "Name is required" there is any body can help me

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "YourResoruceName")]
```

Comment: sorry but i use [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Texts), Name = "uname")] for display name and it work correctly so why for required dos'nt work